# C++ script behaving badly when using "string" data type

Tags: c++, string, io

I just want to write a simple script that asks for someone's name and prints it out. But for some reason, when I use the string data type it just kind of, does nothing.

Here is the code and output if I use a string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;

    cout << "Please give me your name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, it just runs the .exe and nothing happens. However if I take the C approach to strings and use a character array and also don't use getline(), it works fine (but doesn't skip the '\0' character):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //string name;
    char name[15];

    cout << "Please give me your name: ";
    //getline(cin, name);
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I have tried a few other approaches and all have worked fine. For some reason, making the variable *name* as a string data type makes it behave weirdly. I tried looking around some C++ based books and the web but no one seems to have 
 had this problem.

I'm just going to add this for clarification, I checked to see if the program was just executing too fast for me to see what was going on. It is not doing that, it even skips the part where it is supposed to wait for input.

I am using Visual Studio Code to write the programs and MinGW to compile. I took my code and ran it over at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and it worked as expected:

[image]

Could this possibly be a Windows or Command Prompt problem?

Comment: You changed two things between one "script" and the next. I suggest changing one thing at a time.

Comment: BTW there are no _C++ scripts_, only _C++ programs_.

Comment: The first snippet works fine on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04, g++5.4.0).

Comment: No one is going to be able to replicate the problem you say you have with the first program. You must be doing something you do not tell us.

Comment: cin.ignore() should be used before getline.

Comment: Both programs are fine, there may be a problem with your installation, or the code you run is not the code you compile, or there is something else you didn't tell us.

Comment: No problem with first code snippet.

Comment: Step through the program with your debugger. You don't know how to use your debugger? Then it's time to start learning now.

Comment: As a possible cause of the problem, are you compiling the source you *think* you are compiling? If you do e.g. `type Lab1.cpp` do you see the source you expect?

Comment: I find it better to place `ignore` after a read with known trailing bits. If you put it before a read you may find yourself ignoring data you do want.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on STL implementation and OS, `std::cout` may be buffering data in memory. It typically does not flush buffered data to console until either:

- a threshold is reached
- a `'\n'` character is output
- `std::cout.flush()` is called (which includes outputting `std::endl`, which calls `flush()` after writing a line break).

Try calling `std::cout.flush()` (directly, or via `std::flush`) after outputting the prompt and before reading the `name`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    cout << "Please give me your name: " << flush;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By default `cin` is [`tie()`'d](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie) to `cout` and should call flush before attempting any input.